# Glass texture restricted to certian parts of the mesh

Tags: modeling

I've been working on a little bird but encountered an issue, I can't get it so that the glass texture is restricted to the faces I have selected.

[image]

Comment: I just had to add a second material...solved

Comment: add the material and assign it to the selected faces.